# SQL Server Jobs and Schedules - New schedule per job or re-use?

Tags: sql-server

Not a technical question as such, but I do wonder how other people deal with the Schedules in SQL Server in relation to SQL Agent.

Personally, I like to create a bunch of schedules and then reuse them for various jobs.

As an example, I like to name my schedules in the following manner:

- Daily - Every 15 seconds midnight to midnight
- Daily - Every 15 seconds between 03:20 and 23:55
- Daily - Every 22 minutes from midnight to midnight
- Daily - Every 3 hours - starting at 03:30 to 23:59:59
- Daily - Every 30 seconds from 00:00:05

It's not that stringent, but it helps me to understand the schedules a little better.

And then, I like to associate my jobs with existing schedules (the rule in the team is : DO NOT modify schedules)
So I do end up with a number of schedules that are linked to numerous jobs.

Discussing this with a colleague and wondering what is the correct approach, most efficient approach to this, we tested things a little. 
One behaviour I thought was surprising is as follows:

- create a new job
- during that process, create a new schedule and associate it to that job
- run the job once (mine was "SELECT 1 as one") to be sure to be sure
- then drop that SQLAgent job

I would have expected the schedule to remain, but as it turns out the newly created schedule is also dropped!

How do others feel about that? is this correct behaviour?
And do you prefer to create a new schedule for every new job you create? or re-use Schedules?

Hoping to hear interesting views,

Kindest,

B

Comment: Your question is likely to be closed as primarily opinion-based and therefore off topic. Regarding your observation about schedules being dropped, specify the [`sp_delete_job` `@delete_unused_schedule=0`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-delete-job-transact-sql) parameter to retain unused schedules. The default is `1` so unused schedules are dropped.

Comment: Thanks for that information about retaining schedules, I didn't know that! +1 from me! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is entirely opinion based, but I also won't be surprised if it gets flagged as such.

In the shop where I had the most sway over job scheduling, we opted to create new schedules for each job. Sometimes just one, sometimes several. That way, if we were experiencing high load on any given server, we could tweak individual job schedules to spread out the load without impacting multiple jobs. Say, for instance, one of 6 jobs with the same start time started to process exponentially more data, that one job could easily be shifted by X minutes so it wasn't competing for resources, or causing competition.

Comment: Hi Eric,
Thanks very much for your opinion (and yes that was totally what I was asking for!) - I find it informative and the aperçu in your experience with tweaking schedules is useful,

Comment: Glad it was useful. :)